# Notify when unread mail through office 365 app(ionic mobile app)

Tags: javascript, angularjs, ionic-framework, office365api

I am creating an ionic mobile application which will notify the user of the app when they have some unread mail from their office 365 account. I have spent hours on this piece of code trying to figure out where it is going wrong. if anyone can find a reason why this piece of code isn't working, that would be much appreciated. Thank you.

```
(function () {
'use strict';

angular.module('app365').controller('homeCtrl', ['$scope', '$stateParams', '$ionicLoading', '$ionicPopup', 'app365api', homeCtrl]);

function homeCtrl($scope, $stateParams, $ionicLoading, $ionicPopup, app365api) {
    var vm = this;
    var outlookClient;

    // Get mail list.
    function getMails() {
        var filterQuery = '';

        // Get all mails flagged as important.
        if (typeof $stateParams.important != 'undefined') {
            getImpMails();
            return;
        }

        // Get all unread mails.
        if (typeof $stateParams.unread != 'undefined') {
            filterQuery = 'IsRead eq false';
        }

        NProgress.start();
        // Fetch Inbox folder
        outlookClient.me.folders.getFolder("Inbox").messages.getMessages().filter(filterQuery).fetch()
            .then(function (mails) {
                // Get current page. Use getNextPage() to fetch next set of mails.
                vm.mails = mails.currentPage;
                $scope.$apply();
                NProgress.done();
            });
    };
    if ($scope.result() == null) {
        null;
    } else {
        $ionicPlatform.ready(function () {

            $ionicPopup.confirm({
                title: "You have unread mail",
            })
            .then(function (result) {
                if (!result) {
                    ionic.Platform.exitApp();
                }
            });
        }

    )
    }
}
}

)
```

> Error: [ng:areq] Argument 'homeCtrl' is not a function, got undefined

This is the error I receive even though homeCtrl is a function and had already been referenced.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are missing the `()` at very end that invoke your [IIFE](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8228281/what-is-the-function-construct-in-javascript). Therefore the controller is not being registered since the function never runs.

Change

```
(function() {
    'use strict';

    angular.module('app365').controller('homeCtrl', ['$scope', '$stateParams', '$ionicLoading', '$ionicPopup', 'app365api', homeCtrl]);

    function homeCtrl($scope, $stateParams, $ionicLoading, $ionicPopup, app365api) {
      // code removed for clarity

    }
  }
)
```

To

```
(function() {
    'use strict';

    angular.module('app365').controller('homeCtrl', ['$scope', '$stateParams', '$ionicLoading', '$ionicPopup', 'app365api', homeCtrl]);

    function homeCtrl($scope, $stateParams, $ionicLoading, $ionicPopup, app365api) {
      // code removed for clarity

    }
})();
//^^ missing braces
```

Comment: Thank you, this has now gotten past the error.
Next step is trying to get this to work

Comment: *"doesn't work"* is far too broad for a problem statement